# How to bind guid on table ng repeat using angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

by using following code am generating Guid

```
  //sal urn
    $scope.getGUIDSal = function () {
        var d = new Date().getTime();
        var uuid = 'xxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
            var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
            d = Math.floor(d / 16);
            return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
        });
        return uuid;
    }

    $scope.URN = $scope.getGUIDSal();
```

this is my table grid, if multiple rows created i want create new guid for each row ,

```
<table >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SNo</th>
                                <th>URN</th>

                                <th>Amount</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="sal in SalaryDetails">
                                <td class="label-center">
                                    {{$index + 1}}

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{URN}}
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    {{sal.Amount}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

by using above code am binding same guid for each row

Comment: You may call `getGUIDSal` in the view to generate new `guid`  for each row

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tweak the code little bit

```
$scope.getGUIDSal = function () {
        var d = new Date().getTime();
        var uuid = 'xxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
            var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
            d = Math.floor(d / 16);
            return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
        });
       return uuid;
}

//$scope.URN = $scope.getGUIDSal(); //remove this
```

And inside view you can do this

```
 <td>
    {{getGUIDSal()}}
 </td>
```

If this doesn't work, you can initialize a new scope variable inside `getGUIDSal ()` and use it inside view.

---

Instead of `return uuid;`

you can do:

```
$scope.URN = uuid;
```

And use `$scope.URN` inside view

Comment: Thank you for responding Dhaval, both not working , complete table not displaying if i use this

Comment: @sumangoud There might be errors in console check that too. it should work!

Comment: binding guid in table  but , it continuosly changing guid by using that code

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id of the salary to the function and generate guiid and return to the view.

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="sal in SalaryDetails">
 <td class="label-center">
  {{$index + 1}}
 </td>
 <td>
  {{getGUIDSal(passid)}}
 </td>
 <td>
   {{sal.Amount}}
 </td>
 </tr>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.getGUIDSal = function (someid) {
        var d = new Date().getTime();
        var uuid = 'xxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
            var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
            d = Math.floor(d / 16);
            return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
        });
        return uuid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<td>
{{ getGUIDSal() }}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach using directive (Run code snippet):

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);

  function HomeController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.salaryDetails = [{
      amount: "$1500"
    }, {
      amount: "$2000"
    }, {
      amount: "$5100"
    }];
  }
  app.controller("HomeController", [HomeController]);

  function urn() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var d = new Date().getTime();
        var uuid = 'xxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
          var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
          d = Math.floor(d / 16);
          return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
        });
        element.html(uuid);
        //In case you want to add as attribute of td
        element.attr("urn",uuid);
      }
    }
  }
  app.directive("urn", [urn]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="HomeController as homeCtrl">

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>SNo</th>
          <th>URN</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="sal in homeCtrl.salaryDetails">
          <td class="label-center">{{$index + 1}}</td>
          <td urn></td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{sal.amount}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```